# Filter object list using ids in an array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object list and each object has a specific code. There is another array with these specific codes and I want to retrieve all the objects which match codes in the array. I tried with grep function and indexOf method but I don't receive any results. Can someone help me with this?

```
    var selectedCodes = [2, 12, 15];

    var objArray = [
    {
        "ItemID": "1",
        "ItemName": "Name1",
        "ItemCode": "1",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "2",
        "ItemName": "Name2",
        "ItemCode": "2",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "3",
        "ItemName": "Name3",
        "ItemCode": "10",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "4",
        "ItemName": "Name4",
        "ItemCode": "12",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "5",
        "ItemName": "Name5",
        "ItemCode": "15",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "6",
        "ItemName": "Name6",
        "ItemCode": "20",
    }
];
```

According to the above object list and array, I need to get Name2, Name4, Name5 objects only into a different list. Below you can find the code I'm using for this. But I have no luck with that

```
var selectedObjects = $.grep(objArray, function (e) {
    return selectedCodes.indexOf(e.ItemCode) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var selectedCodes = [2, 12, 15];

    var objArray = [
    {
        "ItemID": "1",
        "ItemName": "Name1",
        "ItemCode": "1",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "2",
        "ItemName": "Name2",
        "ItemCode": "2",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "3",
        "ItemName": "Name3",
        "ItemCode": "10",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "4",
        "ItemName": "Name4",
        "ItemCode": "12",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "5",
        "ItemName": "Name5",
        "ItemCode": "15",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "6",
        "ItemName": "Name6",
        "ItemCode": "20",
    }
];

var filteredData = objArray.filter(function(item) {
  return (
    selectedCodes.indexOf(parseInt(item.ItemCode)) > -1
  );
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Use `filter` to filter out the matching records.

Reference: [Filter Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Can I use => operator? I get syntax error. Im working on kind of old project with Jquery

Comment: @user2837480 I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: I realized that my problem is with im not parsing code into int. Actually my Itemcode is a string one. Because I'm not sure it will be always a number. Somehow when I'm getting these codes into the array it comes as int array. Why is that? The selectedCodes array I'm using above, im taking it from another function.

using below code

selectedCodes = $('#tblgridItems tr.itemactive').map(function () {
            return $(this).data('itemcode');
        }).get();

Comment: In that scenario, change your code to `$('#tblgridItems tr.itemactive').map(function () { return parseInt($(this).data('itemcode')); }).get();`. Before returning change it to integer.

Answer (score 1):

For an `O(n)` solution, first construct an object whose keys are the codes, then `.map` the `selectedCodes`:

```
const objsByCode = {};
for (const item of objArray) {
  objsByCode[item.ItemCode] = item;
}
const result = selectedCodes.map(code => objsByCode[code]);
```

```js
var selectedCodes = [2, 12, 15];

var objArray = [{
    "ItemID": "1",
    "ItemName": "Name1",
    "ItemCode": "1",
  },
  {
    "ItemID": "2",
    "ItemName": "Name2",
    "ItemCode": "2",
  },
  {
    "ItemID": "3",
    "ItemName": "Name3",
    "ItemCode": "10",
  },
  {
    "ItemID": "4",
    "ItemName": "Name4",
    "ItemCode": "12",
  },
  {
    "ItemID": "5",
    "ItemName": "Name5",
    "ItemCode": "15",
  },
  {
    "ItemID": "6",
    "ItemName": "Name6",
    "ItemCode": "20",
  }
];

const objsByCode = {};
for (const item of objArray) {
  objsByCode[item.ItemCode] = item;
}
const result = selectedCodes.map(code => objsByCode[code]);
console.log(result);
```

No need for a big library like jQuery to achieve something this trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectedObjects = objectArray.filter(
  obj => selectedCodes.includes(Number(obj.ItemCode))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve it by simple modify:

```
var selectedObjects = $.grep(objArray, function (e) {
    return selectedCodes.indexOf(e.ItemCode - 0) > -1;
});
```

You are actually comparing String to Number. casting ItemCode to Number will solve it.

Answer (score -1):

you can do with simple for loop logic.,

```js
  var selectedCodes = [2, 12, 15];

    var objArray = [
    {
        "ItemID": "1",
        "ItemName": "Name1",
        "ItemCode": "1",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "2",
        "ItemName": "Name2",
        "ItemCode": "2",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "3",
        "ItemName": "Name3",
        "ItemCode": "10",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "4",
        "ItemName": "Name4",
        "ItemCode": "12",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "5",
        "ItemName": "Name5",
        "ItemCode": "15",
    },
    {
        "ItemID": "6",
        "ItemName": "Name6",
        "ItemCode": "20",
    }
];
var selectedArra=[];
for(var i=0;i<selectedCodes.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<objArray.length;j++){
       if(parseInt(objArray[j].ItemCode)==selectedCodes[i]){
         selectedArra.push(objArray[j])
       }
   }
}
console.log(selectedArra)
```

Comment: not by me. but I was expecting some Jquery function.

Comment: you didn't mention dude. any ways no problem